# How to make local library available as a installed module on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, es6-modules, dredd

Have a look at Dredd, for example, it makes the library Hooks available when you are running a script with the `dredd`command.

**Command line**

```
$ dredd [...] --hookfiles=./hooks.js
```

**hooks.js**

```
const hooks = require('hooks');
...
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of Dredd. In Dredd's case it's implemented using the [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) library. I think [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) does similar things.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html), which can be used to "link" together local modules as if they were a dependency visible in the `node_modules` directory. This can be very useful when splitting off code into a library. I'm not exactly sure what `dredd` is doing, but it is likely based off of the `npm link` paradigm.